Getting page cannot be accessed when trying to access eCommerce Website
I am trying to install an open source eCommerce called Smartstore
Here is the link for it
https://github.com/smartstore/Smartstore/releases/tag/5.1.0
I put the fles in Smartstore.Community.5.1.0.win-x64.zip in my laptop folder
I installed IIS from Windows Features
and have it like this

when i try to access the website, i get this error

I found this question with similar problem
IIS 500.19 with 0x80070005 The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid error
So I did as suggested by installing ASP from Windows Features
but still having the same problem.
Anyone know how to fix that?

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500.19 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
